# Terminal stops finding tcsh directory after some time

Tags: terminal, tcsh

On my system I have zsh and tcsh installed. I usually use zsh but some scripts use tcsh. Normally, in a terminal window, if I type

```
tcsh
mec-0569x:~>
```

I get the prompt up as expected. If the terminal window has been open for a while, however, and I type tcsh, I get

```
tcsh
tcsh: No such file or directory
tcsh: Trying to start from "/home/james"
mec-0569x:~>
```

I'm not sure if it's related to the time the window has been open, or a particular script I'm running in the window, but if I close the terminal window and open a new one, change directory to the folder I was in, it works perfectly fine. What should I be looking for to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that the directory you were in was removed, and that a new directory with the same pathname was created after that.

This is *not* the same directory; `getcwd()` uses inodes to get the pathname of a directory, this new directory has a different inode, and the inode `getcwd()` want to use doesn't exist anymore.
When you type `tcsh`, it inherits the (nonexistent) working directory from the parent process; on startup, `tcsh` wants to `chdir()` to the current working directory, but this doesn't exist anymore, so you get an error (and it `chdir()`s to the home directory).

You can solve this by `cd`-ing to the full pathname with `cd "$PWD"` before starting `tcsh`, this sets the correct working directory for the parent process.

Comment: What would possible delete a directory (leaving all files intact) and then create a new one replacing all those files?

Comment: @James You mentioned running scripts? Other than that, it's very hard for me to say ... I'm not even *sure* this is your problem, just the most likely based on your question.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the issue.